# Get Device name in XCTest (UITesting)

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uidevice

I am having tough time in finding the device name when running the UITesting for my Target. Below code returns MacBook's name when running on Simulator.

> UIDevice.current.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That´s because you´re running on your Mac and that´s the name of it.

`UIDevice.current.name` returns

> The name identifying the device.

Checkout the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) for what values that UIDevice has to identify it self and the operating system.

So that´s the way to get the device name.

Comment: For me its returning "iPhone Simulator" - when running the app in the simulator **and** running tests on the simulator.  (Xcode 8.1)

Comment: Yes when run on device, It gets me the device name. For simulator I use UIDevice.current.model instead

Comment: @d.felber Even I am using the Xcode but it doesn't return so

Comment: @Manoj, when you´re using the simulator what do you want it to return? The name it returns is Apples Default for the simulator.

Comment: I wanna know Model name now. Say iPhone7 or iPhone7Plus Simulator

Comment: That can´t be done I think for the simulator unfortunately.